# Catch exceptions in custom def() and break

Tags: python, sikuli

I am using several smallish custom defs that get called in an iterator.  In the instance one of the defs catches an exception I want it to quit that definition and keep the script running.  Main flow is as follows:

```
for TIME in QueuedTimes:
    def1(DATE, TIME)
    def2(DATE, TIME)
    def3(DATE, TIME)
```

Assuming all is well in the upstream def1(), I would like the logic of def2() as follows

```
def def2(DATE, TIME):
    <beginstuff>
    while True:
        if exists(fileloaderror):
            print 'found error'
            break
        else:
            print 'pass'
            break
     <end stuff>
```

This `while True` works, but only to evaluate the conditions.  I want the break to jump to the end of `def2()` and proceed to `def3()` and skip all the rest of the `<end stuff>` that would be broken by the exception I hope to catch.  Is there a more trusted way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to exit a function early, use `return`:

```
def def2(DATE, TIME):
    # stuff at the start
    while True:
        if exists(fileloaderror):
            print 'found error'
            break
        else:
            print 'pass'
            return
     # stuff at the end
```

This will break out of the loop *and* skip the stuff at the end.

Comment: def b():
 while True:
  if x==1:
   print 'broken'
   break
 else:
  print x+' pass'
  return

Answer (score 0):

Unless I miss something, the while True is useless as it will exit anyway as soon as it is entered because one of the if ... else ... will break or return the loop.

Why not do:

```
def def2(DATE, TIME):
    # stuff at the start
    if not exists(fileloaderror):
        print 'pass'
        return
    print 'found error'
    # stuff at the end
```